# Given a number N, print sum of all even numbers from 1 to N. Using While loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
number = int(input())
  count = 2
  sum = 0
  while count <= number:
    if count%2 == 0:
      sum = sum + count
    count = count + 1  
print(sum)
```

I did this but still, the code is wrong.

Comment: How exactly is it wrong? What do you expect the result to be? Also, using `sum` as a variable name is bad practice, since `sum()` is a built-in method in python

Answer (score 0):

Given the code above, your main issue is indentation:

```
    number = int(input())
      count = 2
      sum = 0
    ...
```

`count` and `sum` should start where `number` starts as well:

```
    number = int(input())
    count = 2
    sum = 0
    ...
```

Also, you could make your code more efficient by incrementing your `count` by 2, therefore getting rid of the `if` statement:

```
number = int(input())
count = 2
Sum = 0
while count <= number:
      Sum += count
      count += 2
print(Sum)
```

And of course, as Alex P said, avoid using `sum` as a variable name as it is bad practice. Use `Sum`, or any other variation that doesn't look like the method `sum()`.